# No indication of why Apple rejected my TestFlight External build

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I checked iTunes Connect this morning and saw that the status of my pre-release build for external testers had been changed from In Review to Rejected. Unlike normal release submissions, there is no explanation, and no link to the Resolution Center. Also didn't get an email (checked spam).

I've reached out to Apple, but has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Yep, no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Mine was rejected because they needed a demo account, which they mentioned in an email with subject ending in "... has been rejected for beta testing".